# When i am trying to run my flutter app it getting an Error running gradle

Tags: gradle, flutter, dart, sdk, build.gradle

i am getting an error when i trying to run the app. please help. The error in cmd is below -
Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Flutter projects\FlatApp-Firebase-Flutter-master\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Flutter projects\FlatApp-Firebase-Flutter-master\android\app\build.gradle' line: 14
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > ASCII
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
  Command: C:\Flutter projects\FlatApp-Firebase-Flutter-master\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

### Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

line nine in app-build-gradle is below-
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for such a error. I had a similar error. I would suggest you to open your project in android studio and check your gradel versions. I see by the name of you app that you are using firebase. Some of those plugins use Androidx. So migrating your project to Androidx might help. [Here's how to migrate your project to Androidx.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this may because of the incompatibility of Gradle versions.

I opened the android part in Android Studio and updated Gradle as recommended by Android Studio with `Alt+Enter` and it solved my problem.

I can elaborate more if you can post more details about it e.g your app/gradle file.